# Approximation from below of positive elements in tensor product of von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ be two von Neumann algebras.

If $x$ is a positive element of $\mathcal M$ and $y$ is a positive element of $\mathcal N$, it is known that $x\otimes y$ is a positive element of $\mathcal M\overline\otimes\mathcal N$.

So I was wondering : *is every positive element $z$ of $\mathcal M\overline\otimes\mathcal N$ the supremum of the set of all the elements of $\mathcal M\overline\otimes\mathcal N$ of the form
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbf N}x_n\otimes y_n$$ where $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ are finitely supported sequences of positive elements of $\mathcal M$ and $\mathcal N$ respectively such that $\sum_{n\in\mathbf N}x_n\otimes y_n\leq z$ ?*

I wouldn't be surprised if this was not true in general and only worked when $z\geq \varepsilon\cdot 1_{\mathcal M\overline\otimes\mathcal N}$ from some real numer $\varepsilon>0$ or under some condition of a similar fashion.

Comment: If you want that there is a net if positive elements which is a finte linear sum of positive elementary tensors converging to z in SOT, then that will be true. Just use Kalpansky density theorem https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplansky_density_theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It fails for $M=N=M_2(\mathbb C)$. Here $M\overline \otimes N = \mathcal B(\mathbb C^2 \otimes \mathbb C^2)$. Let $e_1 =(1,0), e_2 = (0,1) \in \mathbb C^2$. The rank 1 projection $z$ onto the span of $\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( e_1 \otimes e_1 + e_2 \otimes e_2)$ gives a counter-example. In fact, let $x\otimes y \leq z$. Suppose $x\otimes y \neq 0$, then we may assume $x\otimes y = z$ (since $z$ has rank 1). Write $x_{i,j} = \langle x e_j, e_i\rangle$ for the $(i,j)$'th matrix entry (similar for $y$). Then
\begin{equation}
x_{i,j} y_{k,l} = \langle (x\otimes y) (e_j \otimes e_l) , e_i \otimes e_k \rangle = \langle z (e_j \otimes e_l) , e_i \otimes e_k \rangle = \delta_{i,k} \delta_{j,l} /2.
\end{equation}
Hence $x_{1,1}y_{1,1} = 1/2$, $x_{1,2}y_{1,2} = 1/2$ and $x_{1,1} y_{1,2} = 0$, a contradiction.

So the only positive operator of the form $x\otimes y$ below $z$ is $0$.